# Is there any freely-available open data project of the Rig Veda with the rhythmic meters in it?

Tags: rig-veda, resource

I am wondering if the [vedic meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedic_metre) for the Rig Veda (or other texts) has been encoded into any freely available texts online, such that I can use it in software. That is, the metric structure of each verse is written down in some format digitally, which is available for free use.

Comment: Does https://vedaweb.uni-koeln.de/rigveda/view/index/0 help? It has metrical data too.